# How to create the supercell to simulate a disordered solid solution?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, condensed-matter, disorder

I am trying to simulate the DOS of a disordered semiconductor (Cd<sub>0.5</sub>Zn<sub>0.5</sub>S), my plan is to get the .cif file of `CdS` first, and build a supercell, then I should replace some of the `Cd` atoms with `Zn` atoms to simulate the random replacement, but I am not sure how should I choose which `Cd` atoms should be replaced. Is there any theory to help me understand this issue? Or any tools for this kind of job?

Comment: Similar questions: [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6435/24), [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/90/24), [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1193/24), and [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3550/24).

Comment: A pretty key distinction is whether you are looking for the lowest-energy supercell (ground state), or just any supercell. For the ground state, the answer is [cluster expansion](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/9463/4515), with for example [ICET](https://icet.materialsmodeling.org/) specifically built to be easy to use with "binary alloys" such as what you are asking about. For all others, there are many other options in the links by @Camps.

Comment: Did the comments by Camps and Andrey help?